# Making a button group dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have data coming from a 3rd part API which I can parse using JQuery into multiple arrays which I want to display in a chart. I have taken this out to simplify the code and I'm using two fixed arrays newData1 and newData2

I have successfully created buttons that switch between the two data arrays and change the chart so the chart is dynamic and changes on the button click

What I can't work out is how to make the number of buttons dynamic and populate them from a list - the length of which could vary and is taken from the array called button_list

The function printBn does create a dynamic list of buttons, but I doesn't appears as a button group and take the Bootstrap styling that I've tried to apply like this

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
</div>
```

I basically want a way to make that Bootstrap html dynamic

**charts.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/api/data/';
var newData1 = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9];
var newData2 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
var data = [];
var button_list = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'];

//create an array of arrays
data.push(newData1)
data.push(newData2)

var labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'];
const context = document.querySelector('#myChart1').getContext('3d');

//switch between the arrays and change the data in the chart
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    setChart('radar', 'myChart1', labels, data[0])
});
$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    setChart('radar', 'myChart1', labels, data[1])
});

 //this is my attempt at dynamic a dynimic button group
function printBtn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < button_list.length; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.className = 'btn-secondary';
        var t = document.createTextNode(button_list[i]);
        t.className='btn-group-vertical';
        btn.appendChild(t);    
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
}


$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){  
        //the Json will be parsed here and an array 
        setChart('radar', 'myChart1', labels, newData1)
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

//Create chart
function setChart(chart_type, chart_name, label_array, data_array){
    var ctx = document.getElementById(chart_name);
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: chart_type,
    scaleSteps: 10,
    // Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
    scaleStepWidth: 10,
    // Number - The scale starting value
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    data: {
        labels: label_array,
        datasets: [{
            data: data_array,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'             
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Custom Chart Title',
                    fontSize: 20
                },
               legend: {display: false
                        },
                scale: {ticks: {
                                display: false,
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                min: 0,
                                max: 1,
                                stepSize: 0.2
                              },
                        pointLabels: {
                                  fontSize: 20
                                }
                }
    }
});
}

{% endblock %}
</script>


{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-lg-12' url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}'>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
            <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to make new buttons from `button_list`?

Comment: Yes button_list would be the array populating the buttons text and name. The function I create printBtn does do it but they are ugly and don't have the Bootstrap format of the static code

Comment: Ok, once the buttons are created, where should they go? Do you need any specific `click` event tied to them? Please provide all the needed details.

Comment: Sorry, I had to read through more, I see your attempt.

Comment: At the moment in  the {% block content %} section I have static buttons. I want the dynamic function to replace that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function makeBtns(arr, tObj) {
  $.each(arr, function(k, v){
    var btn = $("<button>", {
      class: "btn-secondary",
      id: v
    }).html(v).appendTo(tObj);
  });
}
```

It would then be used like:

```
makeBtns(button_list, $("body"));
```

This would append 4 buttons to the end of `body` and the HTML would be:

```
<button id="Test1" class="btn-secondary">Test1</button>
<button id="Test2" class="btn-secondary">Test2</button>
<button id="Test3" class="btn-secondary">Test3</button>
<button id="Test4" class="btn-secondary">Test4</button>
```

You might consider a little more complex array.

```
button_list = [{
  element: "button",
  attributes: {
    id: "test-1",
    class: "btn btn-secondary",
    type: "button"
  },
  label: "Test 1"
},{
  element: "button",
  attributes: {
    id: "test-2",
    class: "btn btn-secondary",
    type: "button"
  },
  label: "Test 2"
}];
```

This would need a slightly lighter function.

```
function makeBtns(arr, tObj, replace) {
  if(replace == undefined){
    replace = false;
  }
  if(replace){
    tObj.html("");
  }
  $.each(arr, function(k, v){
    var btn = $("<" + v.element + ">", v.attributes).html(v.label).appendTo(tObj);
  });
}
```

And I would suggest the following code to replace your static buttons. The added lines in the function give y6ou an option to empty the target and then append the option. The default for this is `false` where it would just append.

```
makeBtns(button_list, $(".container > div > .btn-group-vertical"), true);
```

Hope this helps.